# how to load beans on demand in spring boot application

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot

>

---

Hi, I am new to Spring and Hibernate and require a positive response. As per my project requirement , I have a spring boot application and want to load Hibernate Configuration like datasource bean , session factory bean on demand when get the values from user . Based on users database specification values it will create connection there and create tables and perform further tasks . Here is my sample code in which I am excluding the db configuration on initial run and after that  when call the hibernate configure method it creates separate context and  connection with db .The problem is that it is not able to save user values in db and unable to have session factory object autowired in application

Main Application

```
@SpringBootApplication

@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class})

public class TestApplication extends  WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(TestApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

---

Hibernate Persistence.XMl   This are the four beans that i want to load on demand

```
<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        p:driverClassName="${spring.datasource.driver-class-name}" p:url="${spring.datasource.url}"
        p:username="${spring.datasource.username}"
        p:password="${spring.datasource.password}"
        p:initialSize="1" p:maxActive="2"
        destroy-method="close">
    </bean>




    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean"


         p:dataSource-ref="dataSource">
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <value>
                hibernate.dialect=${spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect}
                hibernate.format_sql=true
                hibernate.show_sql=false
                hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
            </value>
        </property>
        <property name="mappingResources">
            <list>

                <value>entity-schema-hbm.xml</value>

            </list>

                </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="testDao" class="com.app.dao.AbstractGenericDao" abstract="true">
        <property name="entityManager">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.SharedEntityManagerBean">
                <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="persistence-test-unit" />
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>



    <bean id="transactionManager"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>


    <tx:annotation-driven  />
```

---

Defined method in util for initializing beans it is able to create the separate context and connection with db but not merged with the current application and communicate with db . I want to create connection later on and will be available to spring boot application

```
public  static EntityManager configureHibernate() {
        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext appContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
                "hibernate-persistence.xml");
         dataSource = (DataSource) appContext.getBean("dataSource");
        sessionFactory = (SessionFactory) appContext.getBean("sessionFactory");
         transactionManager = (TransactionManager) appContext.getBean("transactionManager");

         entityManager = (EntityManager) appContext.getBean("testDao");


        UserEntity userEntity=new UserEntity("admin","secret","admin@gmail.com");
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(userEntity);
        try{
            transactionManager.commit();
        }catch (Exception e){

        }


        return entityManager;
    }
```